# Android - No indicator shown when using Jack Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I'm struggling to understand the right way to use Jack Wharton's [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator). So this is what I'm having in my layout:

```
(continued from above)
<com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_eateries"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/viewpager"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And this is how I'm using this in my code:

```
mPager = (ViewPager) app.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, PlaceInfoFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, PlaceMenuFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LocationFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ReviewFragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, PhotoFragment.class.getName()));
        PageAdapter mPageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments, this);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) app.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
        indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        // When swiping between pages, select the
                        // corresponding tab.
                        super.onPageSelected(position);
                    }
            });
```

Apparently I'm missing something important because this is what I get in the result:

[image]

So you can see in the capture that the title are left alligned (while I expect them them to be centered in each tab), and there is no indicator shown. What should I add in my code to make this work? I studied the given sample but I don't see any difference in the code of the `SampleTabsDefault` and `SampleTabsStyled` classes. So if any of you have used this before, please help me out and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest, are you using android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" as the theme for your Activity?

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SampleTabsDefault"
        android:label="Tabs/Default"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator.sample.SAMPLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```